# Cassandra Database Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cassandra, cequel

[image]

Hi guys, when I run rake cequel:keyspace:create or rake cequel:migrate, I get this error. I searched my whole configuration file for 127.0.0.1 and replaced them with localhost:3001 but I still can't get past this error. Any help please? Thank you.

Comment: localhost by default resolves to the loopback address of 127.0.0.1  If you run `ping localhost` you can see this for yourself.  Are you sure that you have the authentication setup correctly?

Comment: Can you tell me where to look to set up authentication?

Comment: Actually, Connection Refused likely means the daemon isn't running.  Running `sudo netstat -plnt` will list the services.  If you run `sudo netstat -plnt | grep 3001` you should see the program running.  I've never used Cassandra personally.